# HQL ManyToOne with different column primary and foreign keys

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have looked through the other similar questions of other people but every given answer doesn't seem to work for me.

I have this 'institution' entity:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "regionId", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Region region;
```

'institution' has `regionId` and the entity 'region' has an `id`.
Exactly the same names as in the Database.
But this gives me a `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: region` error.

The query I use: `Query q = session.createQuery("from Institution where id = :id");` The database has the appropiate relations set with the correct columns.

EDIT:

Region class code:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "region" )
public class Region {
   @Id
   @Column(name="id")
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="region")
   private List<Institution> institutionList = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: Show code for Region  class

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 0):

For bidirectional OneToMany mapping use:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="region")
private List<Institution> institutionList = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: Ah yeah. It was supposed to be `i.id`. I need an institution by its id, with the region it's affiliated with. I see, I see. Let me try this out.

Comment: Then you dont need `join i.region`. Beacuse you are not using it in where condition. region will by fetched.

Comment: The code doesn't crash now but the private property `region` is null. `regionId` is set and there is a `region` with the `id` of the `regionId`. No clue why it isn't working.

Comment: In DB Institution table is regionID also present for record with that ID?

Comment: Yes, it's there ( ignore last comment, I misread it ). It's called regionId. It is a foreign key to the DB region's id (lowercase letters).

Comment: Are ids in both classes annotated with @Id?

Comment: They are, yes. Right above the `private Long id;` properties.

Comment: Create new Region with institution and save it. The try again with this new record

Comment: Tried that now. A new region with a new institution but the region property stays null... Annoying.

Comment: Did you add institution into Region's List<> `region.getInstitutionList().add(region)` ? Also did you called `institution.setRegion(region)` ?